# Facebook graph-API OAuthException Code:368 Misusing this feature by going too fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to publish comments on Pages photos posts by using the following code :

```
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"message" :  @"New Comment"};

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/comments", objectId]
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error Comment %@", [error description]);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Result Comment %@", [result description]);
        }

    }];
```

It works (worked) when I used `NSDictionary *params = @{@"message" :  @"New Comment"};`

But when I tried to use `attachment_url` as parameters value but then I get this error :

```
    error =         {
       message:"(#1705) There was an error posting to this wall";
       type:"OAuthException";
       code:1705
    };
```

I tried to make the calls by using `curl` and Facebook graph-api explorer and I get same errors.
The page I'm trying to comment on doesn't seem to have particular restrictions.

Now I'm getting the following error :

```
FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=368, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 368;
        message = "It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You've been blocked from using it.Learn more about blocks in the Help Center.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}}
```

I guess I reach a limit of something but I don't know which one. What I am suppose to do know to be able to perform requests on `{object-id}/comments` again ?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not and will not officially post any call limits. The reason they give is: "If you are using the platform responsibility you will not hit any rate limits".

It appears to me you are attempting to spam comments to multiple objects and of course they will block this.

So what is you are trying to do?